# AppInventor Android App with customizable information saved on an XML?

Tags: android, xml, url, app-inventor

I want to realize an AppInventor app that opens a remote url using the WebViewer block.

The url must be saved in an xml that is present in the zipped apk file.

In this way, I can distribuite the app on-line, on a php site, customizing the apk, time by time, simply modifying the xml in the zipped apk file via php, and assigning in every apk the right url to open.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, but there also is no need to do something like that....
Just save your URL as variable inside your app and store it in TinyDB. On each run of the app you can check your server if there is something new to download. If yes, update your variable in the app and update it in TinyDB...
In case you like to store an XML file locally, you can save it on the SD card of the device, see an example [here](http://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php#download)...

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear enough, excuse my English ;-)

Each app is distributed as if it were a different app, each with its own url to open.
The php site should 'generate' an app every time different for each user; since it can not compile a java app, i thought it may do this by editing a file in apk file, which is what php can do, since the apk file is in zip format, such as a resource file xml type.

I not think the technique of TinyDB is useful for this case...

Comment: The App Inventor apk file is not in zip format, only the project sources you can download in zip format. Sorry, you can't generate a different app for each user using App Inventor. But it would be doable to open a different URL with the webviewer for each user...